# How can one make a variadic-based chained-indexing function?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

If I have an object `a` that either a built-in array or a class-type with a suitable `operator []`, and its returned type can be indexed itself, how should I write a generic function that can index all of them with a variadic call instead of separated bracket block?  In other words, I can make expressions like:

```
a[i0][i1]...[iK]
```

and I want to be able to write it as a single function:

```
slice( a, i0, i1, ..., iK )
```

since the rules of C++ require `operator []` to work on single arguments, making it less-compatible with variadic stuff.  (This question is based on a Usenet thread where I tried asking something similar; ending up solving only possibly-nested built-in arrays myself.)

A first stab:

```
template < typename T, typename U >
constexpr
auto slice( T &&t, U &&u ) noexcept(???) -> ???
{ return ce_forward<T>(t)[ ce_forward<U>(u) ]; }

template < typename T, typename U, typename V, typename ...W >
constexpr
auto slice( T &&t, U &&u, V &&v, W... &&w ) noexcept(???) -> ???
{
    return slice( ce_forward<T>(t)[ce_forward<U>(u)], ce_forward<V>(v),
     ce_forward<W>(w)... );
}
```

The `ce_forward` function templates are a `constexpr`-marked `std::forward`.  (Some things in the standard that could be marked `constexpr` aren't.)  I'm trying to figure out the right stuff to put in the return type and exception specification spots.  Some cases and caveats I know of are:

- The built-in `operator []` requires one operand to be a data-pointer (or decayed array reference) and the other to be an enumeration or integer type.  The operands can be in either order.  I don't know if an operand could be replaced with a class-type with an unambiguous (non-explicit?) conversion to an appropriate type.
- A class type can define `operator []` as non-static member function(s).  Any such function can only have one parameter (besides `this`).
- The built-in operator can't throw.  (Unless operands could be based on an UDT conversion; said conversion is the only possible throw point.)  The undefined behavior caused by boundary errors is beyond our purview here.
- Whether the last indexing call returns a l-value reference, r-value reference, or value should be reflected in the return type of `slice`.
- If the (final?) call is by-value, then `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<ReturnType>::value` should be OR'd to the exception specification.  (By-reference returns are `noexcept`.)
- If the built-in operator involves an array, the returned reference for that step should be a r-value reference if the array is one too.  (This is kind-of a defect because pointers, unlike arrays, lose their target's l- vs. r-value status, so the traditional return would always be a l-value reference.)
- For class-type indexing operators, make sure the exception-spec and return-type sections refer to the same overload (if more than one) that the function body uses.  Be wary for overloads that differ only in the qualification of `this` (`const`/`volatile`/both/neither and/or `&`/`&&`/neither).

Comment: For what I'm using it for, it should be `constexpr` whenever possible.

Comment: Have you considered simply putting the same expression as in the `return` statement for both return type and `noexcept` specification? E.g. `noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<U>()])) -> decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<U>()])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've come up with a solution, based on the comment by @luc-danton and answer by @user315052.

```
#include <utility>

template < typename Base, typename ...Indices >
class indexing_result;

template < typename T >
class indexing_result<T>
{
public:
    using type = T;

    static constexpr
    bool  can_throw = false;
};

template < typename T, typename U, typename ...V >
class indexing_result<T, U, V...>
{
    using direct_type = decltype( std::declval<T>()[std::declval<U>()] );
    using   next_type = indexing_result<direct_type, V...>;

    static constexpr
    bool  direct_can_throw
     = not noexcept( std::declval<T>()[std::declval<U>()] );

public:
    using type = typename next_type::type;

    static constexpr
    bool  can_throw = direct_can_throw || next_type::can_throw;
};

template < typename T >
inline constexpr
auto  slice( T &&t ) noexcept -> T &&
{ return static_cast<T &&>(t); }

template < typename T, typename U, typename ...V >
inline constexpr
auto  slice( T &&t, U &&u, V &&...v )
  noexcept( !indexing_result<T, U, V...>::can_throw )
  -> typename indexing_result<T, U, V...>::type
{
    return slice( static_cast<T &&>(t)[static_cast<U &&>( u )],
     static_cast<V &&>(v)... );
}
```

I put a [full example program](https://gist.github.com/CTMacUser/5297353) up as a Gist.  It worked on a web-site compiler running GCC >= 4.7, CLang >= 3.2, and Intel C++ >= 13.0.

Comment: `bool direct_can_throw = not noexcept(...)` is `not` supposed to be there?

Comment: @0x499602D2, yes.  The `noexcept` stuff wants to know when we do *not* throw, but my class computes when to throw.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot the `not` keyword was the same as `!` :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the right return value for the `slice` function, you can create a helper template that computes the correct result type. For example:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename... V>
struct SliceResult {
    typedef typename SliceResult<T, V...>::Type Type;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct SliceResult<T, U> {
    typedef typename std::underlying_type<T[U(0)]>::type Type;
};
```

The `slice` function would then return a `SliceResult<...>::Type`.