# Can you throw within a conditional expression? (was: How can bounds-checking be extended to multiple dimensions?)

Tags: c++11, multidimensional-array, conditional-operator, indexoutofboundsexception, throw

**Note:** I solved the original problem by realizing a completely different one.  See the addendum for the new actual problem, but you can read the previous part for context.

This is an extension of one of my [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10171525/1010226).  I made a container class based on that answer:

```
template < typename T, unsigned N0, unsigned ...N >
struct array_md
{
    // There's a class template specialization with no extents.

    // Imagine the various N... components are bracket-enclosed instead
    // of comma-separated.  And if "N..." is empty, then we just have "T"
    // as the "direct_element_type".  (I actually use recursive class
    // definitions.)
    using direct_element_type = T[N...];
    using data_type = direct_element_type[ N0 ];

    template < typename ...Indices >
    auto  operator ()( Indices &&...i )
    noexcept( !indexing_result<data_type &, Indices...>::can_throw )
    -> typename indexing_result<data_type &, Indices...>::type
    { return slice(data, static_cast<Indices &&>( i )...); }

    template < typename ...Indices >
    constexpr
    auto  operator ()( Indices &&...i ) const
    noexcept( !indexing_result<data_type &, Indices...>::can_throw )
    -> typename indexing_result<data_type &, Indices...>::type
    { return slice(data, static_cast<Indices &&>( i )...); }

    data_type  data;
};
```

I'm trying to make a version of `at` for this container.  I figured I'll just make a version of `slice` that takes an exception object.  Unlike the general `slice`, my `checked_slice` has to take in a built-in array object, since pointers and class types (with `operator []`) don't have a (standard) way to give me bounds.

```
template < typename E, typename T >
inline constexpr
auto  checked_slice( E &&, T &&t ) noexcept -> T &&
{ return static_cast<T &&>(t); }

template < typename E, typename T, std::size_t N, typename ...V >
inline constexpr
auto  checked_slice( E &&e, T (&t)[N], std::size_t u, V &&...v )
-> typename remove_some_extents<T[N], 1u + sizeof...(V)>::type &
{
    return u < N ? checked_slice( static_cast<E &&>(e), static_cast<T &>(t[ u ]),
     static_cast<V &&>(v)... ) : throw static_cast<E &&>( e );
}

template < typename E, typename T, std::size_t N, typename ...V >
inline constexpr
auto  checked_slice( E &&e, T (&&t)[N], std::size_t u, V &&...v )
-> typename remove_some_extents<T[N], 1u + sizeof...(V)>::type &&
{
    return u < N ? checked_slice( static_cast<E &&>(e),static_cast<T &&>(t[ u ]),
     static_cast<V &&>(v)... ) : throw static_cast<E &&>( e );
}
```

(The `remove_some_extents` does what it says, instead of just one or all the C++11 standard library gives you.)  When I put this into my `at`:

```
template < typename T, unsigned N0, unsigned ...N >
struct array_md
{
    //...
    template < typename ...Indices >
    auto  at( Indices &&...i )
    -> typename remove_some_extents<data_type, sizeof...( Indices )>::type &
    {
        return checked_slice(std::out_of_range{ "Index out of bounds" }, data,
         static_cast<Indices &&>( i )...);
    }

    template < typename ...Indices >
    constexpr
    auto  at( Indices &&...i ) const
    -> typename remove_some_extents<data_type,sizeof...( Indices )>::type const &
    {
        return checked_slice(std::out_of_range{ "Index out of bounds" }, data,
         static_cast<Indices &&>( i )...);
    }
    //...
};
```

I get errors related to array-to-pointer decay!  (I'm using TDC-GCC 4.7.1 that's bundled with CodeBlocks 12.11 for Windows-8 Pro 32-bit.)

```
In file included from container/array_md.hpp:36:0,
                 from test\arraymd_test.cpp:15:
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const int; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const int; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
container/array_md.hpp:284:112:   required from 'constexpr const typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) const [with Indices = {int}; T = int; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = int]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:224:1:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: warning: returning reference to temporary [enabled by default]
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [2][6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
container/array_md.hpp:284:112:   required from 'constexpr const typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) const [with Indices = {int}; T = char [6]; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {2u}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = char [2][6]]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:238:1:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const char (&)[2][6]' from expression of type 'const char (*)[6]'
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [2][6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]' not a return-statement
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:141:10:   required from 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]'
container/array_md.hpp:284:112:   required from 'constexpr const typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) const [with Indices = {int, int}; T = char [6]; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {2u}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = char [6]]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:239:1:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const char (&)[6]' from expression of type 'const char*'
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]' not a return-statement
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
container/array_md.hpp:284:112:   required from 'constexpr const typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) const [with Indices = {int, int}; T = char [6]; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {2u}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = char [6]]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:239:1:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const char (&)[6]' from expression of type 'const char*'
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]' not a return-statement
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {unsigned int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
container/array_md.hpp:284:112:   required from 'constexpr const typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) const [with Indices = {int, unsigned int}; T = char [6]; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {2u}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = char [6]]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:261:5:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const char (&)[6]' from expression of type 'const char*'
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {unsigned int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]' not a return-statement
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = int; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = int; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
container/array_md.hpp:274:112:   required from 'typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) [with Indices = {int}; T = int; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = int]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:220:1:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'remove_some_extents<int [2], 1u>::type& {aka int&}' from an rvalue of type 'int'
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = int; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = int; std::size_t = unsigned int]' not a return-statement
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [2][6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
container/array_md.hpp:274:112:   required from 'typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) [with Indices = {int}; T = char [6]; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {2u}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = char [2][6]]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:234:1:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char (&)[2][6]' from an rvalue of type 'char (*)[6]'
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [2][6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]' not a return-statement
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:141:10:   required from 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]'
container/array_md.hpp:274:112:   required from 'typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) [with Indices = {int, int}; T = char [6]; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {2u}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = char [6]]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:235:1:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char (&)[6]' from an rvalue of type 'char*'
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]' not a return-statement
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
container/array_md.hpp:274:112:   required from 'typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) [with Indices = {int, int}; T = char [6]; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {2u}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = char [6]]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:235:1:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char (&)[6]' from an rvalue of type 'char*'
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]' not a return-statement
utility/slice.hpp: In instantiation of 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {long double}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
container/array_md.hpp:274:112:   required from 'typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type& container::array_md<T, M, N ...>::at(Indices&& ...) [with Indices = {int, long double}; T = char [6]; unsigned int M = 2u; unsigned int ...N = {2u}; typename remove_some_extents<typename container::array_md<T, N ...>::data_type [M], sizeof (Indices ...)>::type = char [6]]'
test\arraymd_test.cpp:260:5:   required from here
utility/slice.hpp:141:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'char (&)[6]' from an rvalue of type 'char*'
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: error: body of constexpr function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {long double}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]' not a return-statement
utility/slice.hpp: In function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {unsigned int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
utility/slice.hpp: In function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
utility/slice.hpp: In function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
utility/slice.hpp: In function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = const char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = const char [2][6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
utility/slice.hpp: In function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {long double}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
utility/slice.hpp: In function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {int}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
utility/slice.hpp: In function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
utility/slice.hpp: In function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = char [2][6]; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = char [2][6]; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
utility/slice.hpp: In function 'constexpr typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type& checked_slice(E&&, T (&)[N], std::size_t, V&& ...) [with E = std::out_of_range; T = int; unsigned int N = 2u; V = {}; typename remove_some_extents<T [N], (1u + sizeof (V ...))>::type = int; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
utility/slice.hpp:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

I thought using array references cancels array-to-pointer decay.  Is this a GCC bug, or am I messing up somewhere?

For "slice.hpp", Line 141, Col. 10 is the end of the statement in the (l-value version of) `checked_slice` function, while L142C1 is the function's ending bracket.  In "array_md.hpp", L284C112 and L274C112 are return (and sole) statements of the `at` functions, `const` and non-const respectively.  The column is at the "i" inside the `static_cast`.

By the way, here's `remove_some_extents`:

```
// Forward declaration
template < typename Array, std::size_t Count >
struct remove_some_extents;

// Case with indefinite array but no extents to strip
template < typename T >
struct remove_some_extents< T[], 0u >
{ typedef T type[]; };

// Case with definite array but no extents to strip
template < typename T, std::size_t N >
struct remove_some_extents< T[N], 0u >
{ typedef T type[N]; };

// Case with non-array type but no extents to strip
template < typename T >
struct remove_some_extents< T, 0u >
{ typedef T type; };

// Case with indefinite array and extents to strip
template < typename T, std::size_t L >
struct remove_some_extents< T[], L >
{ typedef typename remove_some_extents<T, L - 1u>::type type; };

// Case with definite array and extents to strip
template < typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t L >
struct remove_some_extents< T[N], L >
{ typedef typename remove_some_extents<T, L - 1u>::type type; };

// Right now, non-array type with non-zero strip count should give an error.
```

Thanks.

**Edit:** Added the base-case and r-value overloads for `checked_slice`.

**Addendum:** I got something that works, but I don't know why the old way didn't work.

I first commented out the r-value overload for `checked_slice`, to reduce the variables I have to work with.  I then made a version of `checked_slice` that works for standard containers, but you don't need to see it because it didn't help.  (And I commented it out to make sure it didn't make a difference.)

I changed the regular version to:

```
template < typename E, typename T, std::size_t N, typename ...V >
inline constexpr
auto  checked_slice( E &&e, T (&t)[N], std::size_t u, V &&...v )
 -> typename remove_some_extents<T[N], 1u + sizeof...(V)>::type &
{
    return checked_slice( static_cast<E &&>(e), static_cast<T &>(t[ u ]),
     static_cast<V &&>(v)... );
}
```

i.e. I removed the actual test and the throw-on-fail parts, and the code worked!  The problem didn't seem to be the indexing, but the throw and/or conditional!  Sure enough, when I changed it to:

```
template < typename E, typename T, std::size_t N, typename ...V >
inline
auto  checked_slice( E &&e, T (&t)[N], std::size_t u, V &&...v )
 -> typename remove_some_extents<T[N], 1u + sizeof...(V)>::type &
{
    if ( u < N )
        return checked_slice(static_cast<E &&>(e),t[u],static_cast<V &&>(v)...);
    else
        throw e;
}
```

It still works!  What gives, I thought it was OK to use a throw statement as one of the action parts of a conditional expression?  Is it a bug in my compiler?

I may have to give up and separate the bounds-check to a pure-function and throw-on-fail within the `at` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I changed this question, it may have not been flagged as a new one.  I got [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16247205/1010226) from re-asking in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16246123/1010226), and it worked.